# how to convert multiple insert into one insert using python

Tags: python, sql

I have a sql file in which there are many insert sql to the same table: 
insert into tbname 
values (xxx1);

```
insert into tbname values (xxx2);

insert into 
tbname values (xxx3);
...
```

how to convert this file into a new file containing one sql like :

```
insert into tbname (xxx1),(xxx2),(xxx3)...;
```

Due to different insert formats as above in the sql file, it make hard to use regular express in python.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert multiple rows into the table use `executemany()` method.

```
   mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
      host="localhost",
      user="yourusername",
      passwd="yourpassword",
      database="mydatabase"
    )

    mycursor = mydb.cursor()
    sql = "INSERT INTO tbname VALUES (%s)"
    val = [
      ('xx1'),
      ('xx2'),
      ('xx3')
    ]

    mycursor.executemany(sql, val)
    mydb.commit()
```

For more info, follow [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But the situation is that I only have the multiple insert clause in the file. First of all I need to convert it.

Comment: You can use a programming language to convert those previous insert statements into a single statement and write to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Open your file to a string and use split to get all values in a table and then again to a string. Something like:

```
s = "insert into tbname values (val1, val2);insert into tbname values (val3, val4);insert into tbname values (val5, val6);"
values = s.replace(";insert into tbname values", ', ')
```

It's an anorthodox method but could work in your case to get it in one insert.

Comment: Thanks for your kind help! s.replace(";insert into tbname values", ', ')  ,  tbname is unkown or could insert into different tables, any suggestions

Comment: I did not quite get that. Give me a few more info to help you!

Comment: please see my comment